# reload page with next/prev button on framework7

Tags: html-framework-7

I have a page that on init call a function with a page number…

```
myApp.onPageInit('content', function (page) {
 var page = page.query.page;
 my_function(page);
});
```

And is called first time with

```
<a href=“content.html?page=1”>…</a>
```

Then on bottom I have

```
<a href=“content.html?page=1” class=“prev”>prev page</a>
<a href=“content.html?page=2” class=“next”>next page</a>
```

But on click I have white page…
If I add **reloadPages: true** seems working, but I have problem with back page…

Then, how to reload current page in correct way?

Thanks